# conversion of IBM RPG file to C#

Tags: rpg

As per requirement we need to convert the IBM RPG code file to C# code. We have researched for a third party tool to convert the RPG code, but we couldn’t find such free tool.  Another option in-front of us is, create our own logic to convert each line by line of RPG code to C#.  But issue is we are not familiar with RPG programming. If you have any references to convert the IBM RPG code file to C#, It would be helpful for us.

Comment: maby you should spend less time searching a tool to convert and use the time to manually convert the code from RPG III (I assume) to C#. Since those are 2 completly different approaches and platforms, this is not possible so easily. 
In C# you have to setup some connection to the i System and the database. in RPG you just include the database file within the F-Specs.
May you tell us something about the program and what it does?

Comment: There are other issues as well. RPG is a procedural language, and C# is object oriented. How do you plan to build the object scaffolding around the procedural code? There was a company (intentia) who did this with Java (that is converted RPG to Java). They ended up with Java that looked like RPG rather than a good Java program that looked like Java. Probably not what you want to do. A better idea is to find out what the RPG programs do, and rewrite using C# techniques. RPG is actually a very simple language to learn, and if you convert to free form RPG IV, it is surprisingly powerful.

Comment: I quote the other comment, the simple way is re-write code in C# (if you don't want to pay a specialized tool). The big difference between two languages is the different approch (procedural vs OOP).